# Separable states of maximum non-classical correlations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

Although there is no standard measure of entanglement, the GHZ states

$|GHZ\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle^{\otimes n}+|1\rangle^{\otimes n})$

are often deemed as maximally entangled states of $n$ qubits. We know by now that even separable states can exhibit correlations that are impossible in the classical world. This makes me wonder: is there a similar characterization of *separable* states that exhibit maximum non-classical correlations?

For example, I imagine that states of the form

$\rho=(1/4)(|0\rangle\langle 0|\otimes|+\rangle\langle +|)+(|1\rangle\langle 1|\otimes|-\rangle\langle -|)+(|+\rangle\langle +|\otimes|1\rangle\langle 1|)+(|-\rangle\langle -|\otimes|0\rangle\langle 0|)$

are two-qubit separable states with maximum correlations. Is this true? Is there a general notion for $n$ qubits?

Comment: How did you construct $\rho$ ?

Comment: I saw it mentioned in [link] http://prl.aps.org/abstract/PRL/v100/i5/e050502. (Also, I was missing a normalization factor). Intuitively, one can think of non-classical correlations as arising from having correlations between non-orthogonal states, as in the example. This state also has the property that its reduced states are completely mixed, like they are for maximally entangled states.